# Best Strategy to copy database using Secondary Database (not touch primary) to dedicated database server

Tags: sql-server, replication, availability-groups

i have application team that have dedicated database server for datawarehouse. I want to know what is the best way to copy database from secondary.

Current Environment
Always On
1 Primary
1 Secondary Sync -  I want to copy database from here to dedicated server.
2 Secondaries Async

From my point of view, linked server is the best way. But app team, want a copy of the database on the dedicated server.

I appreciate all the ideas and suggestion on this platform. Thank You In Advance.

Comment: [Edit] the question and tell how big the database is. Are there any other constraints? What do you mean by using linked server? Is it production data that needs to be sanitized before passing to developers?

Comment: Does it need to be synchronized in real-time?

Comment: Restore the database from backup.